# Based on Catholic theology, can angels create or destroy matter?

Tags: catholicism, angels, thomas-aquinas, summa-theologica, metaphysics

In the *Summa Theologiae,* St. Thomas Aquinas says that "angels do not assume bodies from the earth or water, or they could not suddenly disappear."

*Source*: [Ia Q. 51 Art. 2 (Whether angels assume bodies) Obj. 3](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/1051.htm)

Based on Catholic theology, does this mean angels cannot destroy matter, if they cannot make earth or water disappear?

Comment: Added source of quote, which turns out to be an objection that St. Thomas refuted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you quoted is an objection that St. Thomas refuted in [Reply to Objection 3](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/1051.htm) in the same Ia. Q. 51 Article 2 :

> Although air as long as it is in a state of rarefaction has neither shape nor color, yet when condensed it can both be shaped and colored as appears in the clouds. Even so the angels assume bodies of air, condensing it by the Divine power in so far as is needful for forming the assumed body.

St. Thomas's explanation in the "I answer that":

> Some have maintained that the angels never assume bodies, but that all that we read in Scripture of apparitions of angels happened in prophetic vision—that is, according to imagination. But this is contrary to the intent of Scripture; for whatever is beheld in imaginary vision is only in the beholder's imagination, and consequently is not seen by everybody. Yet Divine Scripture from time to time introduces angels so apparent as to be seen commonly by all; just as the angels who appeared to Abraham were seen by him and by his whole family, by Lot, and by the citizens of Sodom; in like manner the angel who appeared to Tobias was seen by all present. From all this it is clearly shown that such apparitions were beheld by bodily vision, whereby the object seen exists outside the person beholding it, and can accordingly be seen by all. Now by such a vision only a body can be beheld. Consequently, since the angels are not bodies, nor have they bodies naturally united with them, as is clear from what has been said (Article 1; I:50:1), it follows that they sometimes assume bodies.

So although angels cannot "create" matter, they can "assume" body when permitted by God and facilitated by divine power.  Article 2 does NOT cover the topic whether angels can create/ destroy matter, so we cannot use it to argue either way.

Aquinas's physics is based on Aristotle's physics, which is outdated and worthless now.  Therefore we read Article 2 as simply an affirmation that angels can assume body when God allows.  How this angelic apparation interacts with modern law of physics is left unspecified.

But as a general rule, Christianity believes that **only God can create / destroy matter**. So if an angelic apparation requires creation / destruction of matter, it's not the angels who do them, but God. Although God can suspend laws of nature on a case by case basis (making it a miracle by definition) He may not need to do so to make an angel appear to us.

Comment: He says that these bodies are made out of compressed air and are not made from new matter.

Comment: @KeoBelur That's correct; but that's outdated Aristotelian physics, so that theory is worthless now.  I edited my answer to address your question.  Let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: Since only God can create / destroy matter, does this lead to the conclusion the the pre-mortal Jesus was himself never created as an angel?

Comment: @Lesley I think we need to distinguish **1)** How OT authors interpreted the phenomena, which they identified as "Angel of the Lord", etc. (see [here](https://www.joeledmundanderson.com/the-religion-of-the-apostles-a-book-analysis-series-part-2-yes-second-temple-judaism-understood-god-exist-in-multiple-persons-what/)) and **2)** how NT authors later re-interpret as pre-incarnate Christ (see [here](https://www.joeledmundanderson.com/the-religion-of-the-apostles-a-book-analysis-series-part-3-jesus-christ-in-the-new-testament-the-incarnation-of-the-second-hypostasis-of-god-whats-that-read-on/)).

Comment: I don't think the Bible is explicit on how exactly the manifestations interact with laws of nature (their purpose is theological, not scientific).  This is what theologians like St. Thomas Aquinas do.  I'm not familiar what other theologians's theories on this, and whether there is an updated version of St. Thomas's defense.